# Joining complex curved mesh geometry to object

Tags: modeling, remesh, boolean-modifier

I am struggling in joining two complex mesh objects
[image: the 2 objects in question]
[image: desired outcome]

I have tried multiple options, such as the boolean modifier or manually filling the gaps, but there is always some weird geometry that randomly appears.

Here is the file: [image]

Comment: As Martynas Žiemys says, you can enable the Auto Merge and Split Edges &Faces options, increase the Threshold up to 0.05, select all, press G and Enter right away, it will merge the 2 meshes

Comment: You also have inverted normals on all the sides which will cause shading problems, so once you've merged the meshes select All in Edit mode and Alt-N > recalculate Outside.

Answer (score 1):

You can use various polygonal modeling tools from Mesh, Vertex, Edge and Face menus in Edit Mode to create and join mesh geometry such as Merge(<kbd>M</kbd>/Mesh -> Merge), Make Edge/Face (<kbd>F</kbd> Vertex-> New Edge/Face from Vertices), Grid Fill(Face menu).

You can also find Auto Merge feature for transform operators like <kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd> that can be useful since it can merge and split overlapping geometry during transform operations.

[image]

Geometry doesn't ever appear randomly in Blender. It is always a result of some operation, so you have to make sure you know how every function works before using it. A good place to start if you want to find out how some function works is [Blender's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/index.html). Like for example, if I wanted to understand what Merge does, I can look for it and find this: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/merge.html Experimenting is also a good idea. Once you understand how the tools work, you can use them effectively.